# Tagging several groups of equations in the same environment

Tags: equations, tags

I have long equations, so I have to break them with this structure:

```
something = long expression1
continuation of long expression1
= long expression2
continuation of long expression2
= etc
```

What I want to do is to group the first two lines corresponding to expression1 and tag them together. I do this via

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    something = long expression1
    continuation of long expression1
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

This will correctly put a tag in-between the two lines. I want to add to the environment equation the other expressions (i.e. expression2, expression3, etc.):
[image]

This is what I attempted:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Kam =& -\frac{1}{m}\left[\frac{q^2B^2}{4c^2}(\sqrt{2P_1}\cos Q_1 - Q_2)^2 + \frac{q^2B^2}{4c^2}(\sqrt{2P_1}\sin Q_1 - P_2)^2\right]\\
&+\frac{B^2q^2}{8mc^2}\left[\frac{c^2}{q^2B^2}(\sqrt{2P_1}\sin Q_1 + P_2)^2 + \frac{c^2}{q^2B^2}(\sqrt{2P_1}\cos Q_1 + Q_2)^2\right]\\
&+\frac{Bq}{2mc}\left[\frac{1}{\alpha}(\sqrt{2p_1}\cos Q_1 + Q_2)\frac{\alpha}{2}(\sqrt{2P_1}\cos Q_1 - Q_2) \right.\\
&\phantom{+\frac{Bq}{2mc}\left[\right.\,\,} + \left.\frac{1}{\alpha}(\sqrt{2P_1}\sin Q_1 + P_2)\frac{\alpha}{2}(\sqrt{2P_1}\sin Q_1 - P_2)\right]
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
This is my second expression
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

But repeating aligned does not work:
[image]

Comment: Just repeated `aligned` as many time as you wish :-) of course, not in `equation` environment but in `align` or `gather`.

Comment: @Zarko can you write this as an answer? So that the answer does not remain unanswered. Also, how do I align the equal symbols in different aligned environments?

Comment: How is the macro `\Kam` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need some time to figured out your equation, it is huge and wider than text width, so I give up with its simulation ...). With simplifying your equation I obtain the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
Kam & = \text{This is first line  of my first expression}\\
    &\qquad + \text{This is second line of my first expression}\\
    &\qquad + \text{This is third line of my first expression}
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}
    & = \text{This is my second expression}
\end{split}
\end{align}
    \end{document}
```

Main difference is that instead of `equation` I use `align` environment. If you more like to use `aligned` environment instead of `split`, just replace it accordingly. You will obtain the same result.